# Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UITableViewHeaderFooterView'

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, swift2

I'm working on upgrading my project to Swift2, and i got two errors that i don't really why i didn't had them before.

**First one is** "Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass"

**Second one is** "Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UITableViewHeaderFooterView'"

Here is the code of my class:

```
import UIKit
    @IBDesignable
    class CardShadowTableViewHeaderFooterView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

        // MARK: - Public

        override init(frame: CGRect) { <-- First error
            super.init(frame: frame)   <-- Second error
            self.applyCardShadowStyle()
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            self.applyCardShadowStyle()
        }

        // MARK: - Overrides

        override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutSubviews()
            self.updateCardShadowPath()
        }

    }
```

- So why i understand from the first error is that i'm trying to
  override a wrong init of 'UITableViewHeaderFooterView'
- And for the second one that i'm trying to call a non-existent init of
  'UITableViewHeaderFooterView'

True cause the inits of 'UITableViewHeaderFooterView' are

```
public init(reuseIdentifier: String?)
public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

But 'UITableViewHeaderFooterView' also inherit from UIView with the init that i need `public init(frame: CGRect)`

This is the code that i use in my TableViewController to create the header.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerShadowView = CardShadowTableViewHeaderFooterView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,320,45))

        return headerShadowView
    }
```

So there is probably a few things that i don't get and i'm looking for some help and guidance on how to fix my errors and understanding all this mess.

Comment: `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` might inherit from `UIView` but still its designated initialiser is `init(reuseIdentifier:)`. The reason is, that the frame of the view is defined by the table view delegate. So it doesn't make sense to use `init(frame:)`.

Comment: From the swift book: "Unlike subclasses in Objective-C, Swift subclasses do not inherit their superclass initializers by default." Probably best to go read the 'Initialisation' chapter again, specifically the 'Initializer Inheritance and Overriding' section.

Answer (score 5):

A while back I also upgraded an obj-c code base to swift2 and faced the same issues.

This what I ended up doing:

In my custom `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` subclass, I override the initializers.

```
override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

func commonInit() {
//initialize my subviews
}
```

Then in `viewDidLoad` method of the TableViewController, I register the subclass:

```
tableView.registerClass(CustomHeaderFooterView.self,forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "CustomHeaderFooterView")
```

Lastly, in `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` method:

```
let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("CustomHeaderFooterView") as! CustomHeaderFooterView

//do something with headerView

return headerView
```